# entity framework delay some seconds for save?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this problem.

C#, Visual Studio 2010

In the system I have I do add, updates,
For example,
if I add a account and I do the select (using entity framework)
this return successful.

Now I have seen this.
if I add a account and this is saved successful and I stop the project
this account is not saved, 
so I need stay 10 seconds after the change is saved,
this is for add or update a object

Why entity framework takes this delay? Why is it not inserted when I do SaveChanges();

I can I remove this delay?

I am working with a sdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have found why this is happening,  this is necessary close the
>   connection after SaveChanges()  and changes (add or update or deleted)
>   are going to be saved immediately but if  i do not close the
>   connection, then the changes are saved after 10 or 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem is with the Connection.

1.) In EF, before executing a query, it will generate Local Query view for the Database which might take sometime but only for the first time. You can check the same in the below link from MSDN.

[Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

2.) The compact SQL you use might need some library needs to be loaded which is not referenced in your project. So whenever you perform Save, it might got loaded everytime which may take sometime to perfrm save. Add the required Dll's in the reference of your project and try.

Comment: problem was because i did not close the connection, now if i close the connection after SaveChanges() its saved at moment, and if i do not close the changes are saved after some seconds